# Sonarqube eclipse plugin server does not start

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I installed the Sonarqube plugin in Eclipse by following the instructions [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse)

Followed all the steps, restarted Eclispe. Was able to have Sonarqube in Preferences. But when  I go to the servers tab to configure the server (default at `http://localhost:9000`) the test connection fails with the following error:

```
Unable to get version of server http://localhost:9000: Query: http://localhost:9000/api/server/index
```

I read almost all troubleshooting questions. Any suggestions?

Comment: SonarQube server must be started manually.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution existed. It is required to start sonar manually. Apart from the Eclipse plugin, I also had sonarqube installed on my mac. Just cd to the sonar installation directory and start the server. 
And then test the connection in Eclipse. It works.

Comment: Question is about starting sonar from eclipse. Its not always possible to install sonar separately , plugin should also work.